# No package 'alsa' found in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, apt, package-management, sound, alsa

Below is all what I have tried. I don't know what else to try now to remove the alsa not found error. Please guide.

```
$ make

Package alsa was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `alsa.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'alsa' found
Package freetype2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `freetype2.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'freetype2' found
Package webkit2gtk-4.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `webkit2gtk-4.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'webkit2gtk-4.0' found
Package gtk+-x11-3.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk+-x11-3.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk+-x11-3.0' found
Package alsa was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `alsa.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'alsa' found
Package freetype2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `freetype2.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'freetype2' found
Package webkit2gtk-4.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `webkit2gtk-4.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'webkit2gtk-4.0' found
Package gtk+-x11-3.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk+-x11-3.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk+-x11-3.0' found
Makefile:174: recipe for target 'check-pkg-config' failed
make: *** [check-pkg-config] Error 1
```

...

```
$ sudo apt-get install libasound2

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libasound2-data : Breaks: libasound2 (< 1.1.3-5ubuntu0.1)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

...

```
$ sudo apt-get install libasound2-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 alsa-utils : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.1.1)
 gnome-settings-daemon : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.16)
 google-chrome-stable : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.16)
 gstreamer1.0-alsa : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.27)
 ibm-java80-jre : Depends: libasound2
 libasound2-dev : Depends: libasound2 (= 1.1.3-5)
 libasound2-plugins : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.27)
 libcanberra0 : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.16)
 libpcaudio0 : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.16)
 libqt5webenginecore5 : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.16)
 libsdl1.2debian : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.16)
 libsndio6.1 : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.17)
 openjdk-8-jre : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.16)
 pulseaudio : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.24.1)
 skypeforlinux : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.16)
 speech-dispatcher-audio-plugins : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.16)
 spice-vdagent : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.16)
 vlc-plugin-base : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.27)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

...

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 alsa-utils : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.1.1)
 gnome-settings-daemon : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.16)
 google-chrome-stable : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.16)
 gstreamer1.0-alsa : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.27)
 ibm-java80-jre : Depends: libasound2
 libasound2-plugins : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.27)
 libcanberra0 : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.16)
 libpcaudio0 : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.16)
 libqt5webenginecore5 : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.16)
 libsdl1.2debian : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.16)
 libsndio6.1 : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.17)
 openjdk-8-jre : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.16)
 pulseaudio : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.24.1)
 skypeforlinux : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.16)
 speech-dispatcher-audio-plugins : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.16)
 spice-vdagent : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.16)
 vlc-plugin-base : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.27)
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

...

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install   

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 alsa-utils : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.1.1)
 gnome-settings-daemon : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.16)
 google-chrome-stable : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.16)
 gstreamer1.0-alsa : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.27)
 ibm-java80-jre : Depends: libasound2
 libasound2-plugins : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.27)
 libcanberra0 : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.16)
 libpcaudio0 : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.16)
 libqt5webenginecore5 : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.16)
 libsdl1.2debian : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.16)
 libsndio6.1 : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.17)
 openjdk-8-jre : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.16)
 pulseaudio : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.24.1)
 skypeforlinux : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.16)
 speech-dispatcher-audio-plugins : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.16)
 spice-vdagent : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.16)
 vlc-plugin-base : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.27)
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Comment: Do you want to install a audio-config program?   (I Would personally recommend pavucontrol) ?

Comment: I have to compile a JUCE program @William

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For most users, `apt install libasound2-dev` would solve the original problem.

As apt-get complains, your installation is somewhat broken:

You have package libasound2-data installed in version 1.1.3-5ubuntu0.1, but apt does not find package libasound2 of the same version.

This may be the result of removing "bionic-updates" from your apt sources. This can e.g. happen if you unselect "Recommended updates" under "Updates" in `sudo software-properties-gtk`.

In your place, I would do the following:
Ensure that your apt sources receive regular updates:

- Make sure you have recommended updates enabled. Either through `sudo software-properties-gtk`, or by editing `/etc/apt/sources.list` to contain a line like

  ```
  deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
  ```
- `sudo apt update`

After that, your packages should install as expected.

Comment: I will try what you have said. Am thankful to you.